# how select all cell while selected JTable value?

Tags: java, jtable

First i gave all values of row in JTAble. While inserting table values into database, I selected all values of row in JTable, using the following

model.getValueAt(rowIndex,colIndex);

But this method gets all the columns except the last inserted column in a row. If i pressed enter key, after getting all values it done well. How to get all columns in a row with out pressed enter key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to get content of table model, instead of accessing data displayed in the table. Indeed, there may be formatters for displaying content that alter it. Furthermore, the table model reflects the data that is in the table, no matter in which order columns are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question then [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) will explain the problem and give a solution.